# How is force exerted on a wall equal to derivative of hamiltonian with respect to wall position?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm trying to understand a solution of a problem in Landau, Lifshitz "Quantum mechanis. Non-relativistic theory" in $\S22$ "The potential well":

> Determine the pressure exerted on the walls of a rectangular "potential box" by a particle inside it.

The first sentence in the solution makes me wonder how what it says is true:

> The force on the wall perpendicular to the $x$-axis is the mean value of the derivative $-\partial H/\partial a$ of the Hamilton's function of the particle with respect to the length of the box in the direction of the $x$-axis.

Here $a$ is length of the box in $x$ direction. As I understand, this is a result from classical mechanics. But having re-read the chapters on Hamilton's function in "Mechanics" by Landau and Lifshitz, I still don't quite get how the force on the wall appears to be the derivative above.

So, the question is: how to derive this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Assume that the Hamiltonian only depends on $a$ through a potential term $V(a)$. This is the case more often than not. Then

$$\frac{\partial H}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}$$

Now, invoke Newton's second law:

$$ \vec{F}=-\frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec{x} }$$

and the result follows quite simply.

---

Alternatively, we can use the canonical (Hamiltonian) formalism. There, we of course have

$$\dot \pi_a=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial a}$$
where $\pi_a$ is the generalized momentum associated with the coordinate $a$. Of course, $\dot \pi_a$ is also a generalized force, so this is another way to find your result.

Comment: Yes, this was my first thought. But for the context this is used in, quantum mechanics, this seems not quite right: if we try to compute mean potential energy of the particle, it will be zero irrespectively of $a$, thus this derivative will be zero. OTOH, taking the kinetic energy, we'll find that it contributes the whole value of Hamiltonian, and it's the derivative of mean kinetic energy which appears to represent the force. How to solve this apparent conflict?

Comment: @Ruslan I actually figured that 'mean' in this context was meant to imply that we could rely on Ehrenfest's theorem a.k.a. use classical relations, meaning this is the right way to go.